# How to run cordova apps on android 4.4?

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to run the default cordova 3.4 example application on android 4.4.2 API 19.

The app does not open and the message `Unfortunately, exampleapp has stopped.` appears.

Through some research I have found that this has something to do with android 4.4's WebView update.

UPDATE: I was running android 4.4.2 on genymotion, when I run 4.4 on https://www.manymo.com, I see no errors. It seems to me that this issue is specific to genymotion emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update, I was going to post just this:

1. The Cordova team preempted the 4.4 webview release to make sure Cordova was compatible
2. The problem is probably not due to the Cordova-Platform version as we are up to date.
3. Never trust the (Android) emulator. Ever.